# Empty object in generic array breaks type passing?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.6

I'm trying to create a generic function that returns a random item in an array and properly forwards type information using Typescript 2.6.2.

```
function sample<T>(array: T[]) : T {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  return array[index];
}

const obj1 = sample([1, 'a', Symbol('sym')]);
// const obj1: number | string | symbol

const obj2 = sample([1, 'a', Symbol('sym'), {}]);
// const obj2: {}

const obj3 = sample([1, 'a', Symbol('sym'), {a: 'a'}]);
// const obj3: number | string | symbol | {a: string}
```

The type signatures for `obj1` and `obj3` are fine, but for some reason the empty object in the 2nd example causes `obj2`'s signature to get replaced with `{}`.

1. Can you explain why `obj2`'s signature becomes `{}`?
2. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this; I'm getting `obj2` to be `{}` in all versions of TS I've tested.

Comment: Sorry, you're right @jcalz, I should have said `{}`. I'll edit to correct. I'm still confused, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When infering the type, TypeScript tries to find the lowest common subtype of the expressions, which usually
results in a union type. So if you have:

```
const x = [a, b, c]
```

where a, b and c are of type `A`, `B` and `C` respectively, the infered type of `x` is `A | B | C`.
This is exactly what happens for `obj1` and `obj3`. But why `obj2` has type `{}`:

The answer is that TypeScript has structural typing, meaning that if type A has all the properties of type `B`, an instance of `A` is assignable to `B`.
`{}` denotes an empty object type, and since it has no member, any other object type is a subtype of this type. Therefore, the infered type 
`number | string | symbol | {}` is effectively equal to `{}`. (Recall that `A | B` when `A` is a subset of `B` is `B`).